# How Can I Make urxvt Transparent in X11 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xorg, urxvt

I've installed the latest version of X11 (XQuartz 2.5.3) and urxvt with Macports. I want urxvt to be transparent and borderless. My ~/.Xdefaults looks like this:

```
urxvt*foreground:       #ffffff
urxvt*background:       rgba:0000/0000/0000/4444
urxvt*transparent:      true
urxvt*shading:          50
urxvt*depth:            32
urxvt*tint:             white 
urxvt*inheritPixmap:    true
urxvt*borderless:       true
urxvt*scrollbar:        false
urxvt*scrollbar_right:  false
```

But when I launch a urxvt terminal, the background is not transparent and the left scrollbar is present. Also, launching with the transparency example from the urxvt man page does not a transparent terminal make:

```
      urxvt -depth 32 -bg rgba:0000/0000/0000/4444 -fg "[80]pink"
```

Any idea what I can do to get terminal transparency? I've found references to enabling "composition" in the xorg.conf file, but I can't find xorg.conf in OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

> Be warned that rxvt-unicode in MacPorts is compiled without “afterimage” support, and as such doesn’t support images in the background. Getting fake transparency in Os X is also a pain anyway, but by reading the man page and recompiling with afterimage, you should get there.

https://sergeemond.ca/en/articles/rxvt-unicode-on-os-x/